# Loop though items and properties in Sitecore in search for references to media items?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-media-library

I need to loop through some content in a Sitecore solution (recursivly) and seek in all the fields in the item for references to media items. It is a Sitecore 6.5 solution, so out of the box it uses guid's to reference media items. But this is a solution that has been migrated to 6.5, so all media items references are not by guid's but a direct url to the media library.

I need to change this, so all links are referenced with the guid. Any idea on how best to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow the techniques described by Alex Shyba in his publish related media items article:
http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2007/10/publish-related-media-items.html?m=1

To get an collection of all linked items, he uses:

```
yourItem.Links.GetValidLinks();
```

And...

```
Item itm = link.GetTargetItem();
```

Finally, you can test the links to see if they're media items using:

```
itm.Paths.IsMediaItem
```

Apologies for the poor formatting, i'm posting from my phone :)

Comment: This works great - thx :)
But how do i update the actual link once i found it?